# Как отменить alert при отркытии браузера

Tags: java, selenium, alert

При открытии браузера появляется сообщение.

1. Пробовола метод switchTo(), не работает.
2. Получается закрыть сообщение посредством метода Robot(), но в этом случае страница подвисает и я не могу продолжить работу, "выйти" из этого состояния могу только через task manager:
   '''

   ```
    Robot alertAllow = new Robot();
    alertAllow.mouseMove(280, 160);
    alertAllow.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
    alertAllow.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
   ```

'''

3. И еще один способ убрать вообще оповещения не дал результатов:
   '''

   ```
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
    prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2); 
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
   ```

'''
4. Здесь текст всего кода:
'''`    public class my_class {
public static WebDriver driver;

```
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
    
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
    prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2); 
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs); 
            
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    
    }

@AfterClass
public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.quit();
    
}

@Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException, AWTException {
    
    driver.get("https://portal-qa1.maytronics.co/#/login/login");
    // LOGIN - VALID CREDENTILAS
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/app-root/ng-component/div/ng-component/div/form/div/div/mx-input[1]/input")).sendKeys("Shoval.Ziman@comm-it.com");
    Thread.sleep(2500);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/app-root/ng-component/div/ng-component/div/form/div/div/mx-input[2]/input")).sendKeys("123456");
    Thread.sleep(2500);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='mx-button login no-select']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2500);
            
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='icon add_white pointer']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2500);
}

}`
```

'''``

Comment: Добавьте метку библиотеки. По-моему, вы используете selenium

Comment: И язык программирования наверное тоже